# Can i use printf in java without moving to new line

Tags: java, printing, printf

I use System.out.printf method to format the string and print a line but
after that i need to print another line through for loop with print method without moving new line.

Now after used printf method it will move to new line. but i don't need to move new line until print my for loop.

is it possible??
or can u tell any other way

here is my sample code

```
System.out.printf("%7s  %s%n",names[i], " ");
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.print( grades[i][j] + " " );
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: use System.out.println instead of System.out.print

Comment: What do you mean by `without moving new line`? Does this mean, that you don't want to print new line? You should also check the punctuation of your question.

Comment: Rephrased question: how do I remove the `%n` from the `printf`? Sorry, I'm giving the question a *downvote* for not having done enough research on what printf format strings are ...

Comment: sorry iam not well look up on code line and this is need to finish with some amount of time that's y happen ask sorry again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`printf` doesn't by default print a new line. You *really* should read the documentation. When you **explicitly** print a new line using the `%n` newline placeholder, you shouldn't be surprised you get a newline ...

So just remove the `%n` if you don't want it.

Comment: thanks for ur reply... yep it is new line character under there. sorry i never used printf method so i confused

Answer (score 3):

printf wont print a newline by itself, the `%n` at the end of your format String causes the new line . Replacing `"%7s  %s%n"` with `"%7s  %s"` should work.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you need,

> To print the name of students along with their grades in each line.

To accomplish this, you need,

```
for(int i=0;i<number_of_students;i++)
{
 System.out.printf("%7s  %s ",names[i], " ");
                           ^                                 //note the ^
            for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
            System.out.print( grades[i][j]+ " " );
            }
 
System.out.println();
}
```

This will give you something like this :

> *Name*   *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*
>
> *Name*   *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*  *Grade*
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
System.out.printf("%7s  %s%n",names[i], " ");
        for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
        System.out.print( grades[i][j]+ " " );
        }
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.out.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), which doesn't feed a line

Comment: check the javadoc of printf, both behave exactly the same way

Answer (score 0):

You can print outside your loop.

```
String gradesString;
System.out.printf("%7s  %s%n",names[i], " ");
    for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
        gradesString += grades[i][j]+ " ";
    }
System.out.println(gradesString);
```